# Error while installing Magento 2.3 using XAMPP. Cannot open localhost/demowebsite

Tags: magento, xampp

I am a newbie in coding and trying to install Magento using XAMPP on localhost. But I am getting an error while trying to navigate to localhost/demowebsite. How can I get rid of this. Please let me know if I need to give more information.

ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist in C:\xampp1\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp1\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Framewo...') #1 C:\xampp1\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime.php(49): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...') #2 C:\xampp1\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\Framewo...') #3 C:\xampp1\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...', Array) #4 C:\xampp1\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(234): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewo...', Array) #5 C:\xampp1\htdocs\DemoWebsite\index.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framewo...') #6 {main}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `http://localhost/` as domain name with Magento 2, you should at least use `http://localhost.com/`.

I explain how to fix it [just here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458161/1831611).

Hope it'll helps you.