# Magento Open Source 2.3 - CSS and JS not loading

Tags: php, magento, magento-2.0, magento-2.3

I installed Magento 2.3 successfully but when type http://localhost/Magento2/, I get a blank page like this:[image]

and these are the errors found in the console:
[image]

The same issue is also faced on the admin panel. My current version of PHP is 7.2.14.

Comment: We will need more info, what did you install it on? Docker/XAMP/MAMP/Valet+?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `http://localhost/` as domain name with Magento 2, you should at least use `http://localhost.com/`.

1. Change your vHost in Docker/XAMP/MAMP/WAMP... to match your new domain name, for instance `http://localhost.com/`;
2. Edit your **hosts file** with sudo permissions :

   - Debian / MacOS: `/etc/hosts`
   - Windows: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
3. At the bottom of the file, add the following: `127.0.0.1   localhost.com`
4. Go to your Magento db and run the following query :

```sql
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`='http://localhost.com/' WHERE `value`='http://localhost/';
```

5. Finally, with command line :

```sh
cd /YOUR/PROJECT/PATH
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

6. Go to `http://localhost.com/` (or `http://localhost.com/Magento2/`, according to your configuration), and check if everything works.

Comment: What if you only have cPanel access and can't run the shell commands?

Comment: @Cristy, in that case use the trick described here [Magento without command line](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125064/how-to-install-module-magento-2-dont-need-run-command-line-bin-magento-setupup/125090#125090)

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately my shared hosting also has system calls disabled, so it should be a pure PHP solution. LE: Just saw the second option in the answer, trying it now.

Comment: Was able to run the commands as explained there, but still no static files, css missing.

Comment: I am actually not sure running the commands as explained there does anything, it doesn't seem to work though, but it takes time to execute them.

Answer (score 0):

I've same problem and solved by these commands:

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

1. In file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf Navigate <Directory /var/www/>Change "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All"
2. Add this at last in env.php located at <MagentoRootDirectory/app/etc>

```html
'system' => [

       'default' => [

           'web' => [

               'unsecure' => [

                   'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',

                   'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'

               ],

               'secure' => [

                   'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',

                   'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'

               ]

           ]

       ]

   ]
```

3. In etc/di.xml,Search  Under that Modify this Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink to Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
4. Add this in db INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
5. Add this in db UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '0' WHERE core_config_data.path LIKE '%web/seo/use_rewrites%';
   Run this command, sudo a2enmod rewrite